# How to implement Marker Clustering ( Google maps) in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement the Android Maps Utils library in the Xamarin Forms. I want to use marek clustering on the map in the android project. I found in VS for Mac only 0.5.0 versions but when I want to add a package I get an error(is incompatible):

```
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 26.0.2'. MonoAndroid, Version = v7.1 ', MonoAndroid, Version = v7.1', but it is compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I need implements ClusterManager

Do you have any idea how I can use clustering of markers ?

Answer (score 2):

When you install the `Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils` nuget package, only install it in your Xamarin.Android project, as illustrated in the following diagram :

[image]